# How to implement relationships in a pivot model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Today I dealt with implementing Laravel's `hasMany` relation in a pivot model. In my example several vehicles are assigned to a mission through a n:m relationship. Since it's necessary to protocol the vehicles' status, the pivot table `hasMany` logs.

[image]

To attach a relationship it's necessary to implement a pivot model. Take a look here for further information: [How to define custom pivot models in Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#defining-custom-intermediate-table-models)

Our pivot model should look like:

```php
class MissionVehicle extends Pivot
{
    public function logs() {
        return $this->hasMany(Log::class, 'mission_vehicle_id');
    }
}
```

Since Laravel only attaches the `created_at` and `updated_at` attributes automaticallt, it's necessary to attach the id in `withPivot` method:

```php
public function vehicles() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Vehicle::class)
            ->withPivot(['id']) // important!
            ->using(MissionVehicle::class);
    }
```

Now your relationship should work.

Comment: Your code looks correct could you share your controller code, where these are being used/created

Comment: I've updated my post.

Answer (score 1):

Using the ->first()->pivot will give you the intermediate model, I am guessing that that is not what you are after.

```
$mission = Mission::find(1);
$vehicle = $mission->vehicles()->first();
```

Should return the first vehicle that belongs to the pivot. If you want that to return info from the intermidiate use

```
$mission->vehicles()->withPivot(['description'])->first();
```

Or directly in the relation

```
public function vehicles() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Vehicle::class)
        ->using(MissionVehicle::class)->withPivot(['description']);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Actually I wanted to access the `Log` entity through the pivot model.

Comment: I see, not sure how you could do this in a good way, I would probably have a $this->belongsToMany(Log::class)->using(MissionVehicle::class);  so you would get your vehicle as per my example and then get the associated logs through the same pivot

Comment: I've solved it. It's necessary to attach the id attribute to the `withPivot()` method. Updated the post, hopefully it could help someone.